# How to Specify One Worker on a Queue for Delayed Jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, delayed-job

How can I specify one worker for a specific queue when using delayed jobs? I know I can run this command:

```
# Use the --pool option to specify a worker pool. You can use this option 
# multiple times to start different numbers of workers for different queues.
# The following command will start 1 worker for the tracking queue, 
# 2 workers for the mailers and tasks queues, and 2 workers for any jobs:

RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --pool=tracking --pool=mailers,tasks:2 --pool=*:2 start
```

But since we are using heroku we are using a procfile that will run our workers:

`worker: bundle exec foreman start -f Procfile.workers` and our worker file runs the jobs:

```
worker_1: bundle exec rake jobs:work
worker_2: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

What I am wanting to do however, is something like:

```
bundle exec rake jobs:work --queue=specific_queue
```

and only have one worker working on the specific_queue and other workers working on other queues.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at Heroku's `Process Types and the Procfile` docs, you will find [this](http://Process%20Types%20and%20the%20Procfile) example at the end:

> For example, using Ruby you could run two types of queue workers, each
>   consuming different queues:

```
worker:        env QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work
urgentworker:  env QUEUE=urgent bundle exec rake resque:work
```

Delayed Job uses something similar to Resque. It uses the env variables QUEUE or QUEUES to specify the queue for that particular worker.

You can verify that on `lib/delayed/tasks.rb` [source code](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/tasks.rb#L17).

Comment: It did. Thank you

Comment: @jwill would `worker:        env QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work` also process urgent queue?